# How to add Google Chrome to path?

Tags: terminal, bash, google-chrome, path, symlink

I want to add Google Chrome to path under the `google-chrome` name so that I can execute the following command: `google-chrome --version`.

First I tried with:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome /usr/local/bin/google-chrome
```

But I kept receiving pop-ups with an error message (`Google Chrome quit unexpectedly.`). So I tried with `--headless`, i.e. made a script called `/usr/local/bin/google-chrome` and put the following there:

```
#!/bin/bash
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome "$@" --headless
```

But I'm getting:
`ContextResult::kTransientFailure: Failed to send GpuControl.CreateCommandBuffer.`

Made a bit of googling, tried a solution with `--disable-gpu`, but it still does not work.

Note that `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --version` returns the correct version.

Comment: Why do you add `--headless` in the script? I just tried without that, and was able to successfully run `script.sh --version`.

Answer (score 2):

The precise error message reveals that it tries to open additional files relative to the binary you launched.

`macbook:~ tripleee$ ln -s /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome ~/bin/google-chrome`
`macbook:~ tripleee$ google-chrome`
`dlopen /Users/tripleee/bin/../Frameworks/Google Chrome Framework.framework/Versions/120.0.6099.71/Google Chrome Framework: dlopen(/Users/tripleee/bin/../Frameworks/Google Chrome Framework.framework/Versions/120.0.6099.71/Google Chrome Framework, 0x0105): tried: '/Users/tripleee/bin/../Frameworks/Google Chrome Framework.framework/Versions/120.0.6099.71/Google Chrome Framework' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/tripleee/bin/../Frameworks/Google Chrome Framework.framework/Versions/120.0.6099.71/Google Chrome Framework' (no such file), '/Users/tripleee/bin/../Frameworks/Google Chrome Framework.framework/Versions/120.0.6099.71/Google Chrome Framework' (no such file).Abort trap: 6`

The simple and obvious workaround is to make a wrapper script which calls the real binary at its original location instead, without the `--headless` option.

```
#!/bin/sh
exec "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome" "$@"
```

Save as `/usr/local/bin/google-chrome` (or wherever you want it), `chmod a+x`, and go.

Prefer `/bin/sh` over `/bin/bash` as it is significantly smaller, and use `exec` to avoid having the shell hang around waiting for Chrome when it's not going to do anything more after Chrome exits.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need it in the path so that you can run the `--version` command, just do a

```
PATH="/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS:$PATH"
rehash
"Google Chrome" --version
```

Aside from this, I would start chrome from the command line by doing a

```
open -a "Google Chrome".app
```